# which command is better: os.listdir() or os.system('ls') and WHY?

Tags: python, directory

In the current working directory:

```
import os
print( os.listdir() )
```

will list the files and directories. However, I could also get a list of the files and directories in the current working directory of a Linux machine using the `system` command:

```
import os
print( os.system('ls') )
```

Which command is better: `os.listdir()` or `os.system('ls')` and why?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: What if you run that on Windows?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it... if you are just displaying the results and don't care about portability - either (`ls` has a number of useful display options). If you want to process the data then `os.listdir()`. Note: `os.system('ls')` only returns the exit status of `ls`, `ls` actually does the display (you can see this if you remove `print()`)

Comment: I'd go for os.listdir() because is OS independent

Comment: I'd go for `os.listdir` because the result is structured data.

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir()` is implemented natively in python, and will work on any operating system that python is compiled on.

Calling `os.system('ls')` relies on the underlying operating system to have an `ls` command, which is a wild assumption (e.g., what about windows?), and requires this executable to be in the `$PATH`. From a performance standpoint, you'd be executing another process, which is completely redundant. And if you want to do anything fancier than just printing the result, you'll have to mess around with parsing the output yourself.

To make a long story short - don't reinvent the wheel. If python gives you a built-in `os.listdir()`, just use it.

Answer (score 1):

I maybe digging graves here but I recently came across a similar usage.

I tried to `ls` a `/path/to/temp` file. It did not work, the `ls` command would get stuck and unresponsive, for more than 5 minutes before I shut it down. notice this was over SSH via putty, I tried `ls -l | wc -l`, which didn't work either.

`len(os.listdir("path/to/temp"))` returned a number immediately, and it was around `75000`, the list was constructed nearly immediately. So there is a clear speed advantage if you use `os.listdir()` vs ls on directory with a large number of descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Just to pile on: `ls` has an overhead limit to the number of files in the directory you are trying to use it on. `os.listdir()` suffers no such limitation. If you can use it, then `os.listdir()` seems to be the superior choice.